# Saving file to server using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a data string in Javascript and I would like to store it in a text file in my server.

The normal thing to do is to send the data to a PHP medium file to process it and do the file storage part.

This is the code I used but it looks like it doesn't run at all as the destination file `matrice.txt` is still blank :

**script.js**

```
function finalCoords() {

for(var i = 0; i < sort_data.length; i++) {
    matrix = [data.nodes[i].name, sort_data[i].x, sort_data[i].y, sort_data[i].z]; /* This data is collected from other arrays */
    var matrixStr = matrix.join(" "); /* This is the string I want to store */
    console.log(matrixStr); 

    $.ajax({
    url: "matrice.php", /* This is the PHP Medium */
    data : matrixStr,
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: 'post',
    timeout : 5000
    });
  }
}
```

**matrice.php**

```
<?php
    $file="matrice.txt"; /* This is the destination file */
    $text=serialize($_POST); 
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die();
        fwrite($fh, $text."\n");
        fclose($fh);
?>
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the browser console if there is any error ?

Comment: @Leopard : The console doesn't show any error

Comment: See network tab this tells that `post` was successful or not.

Comment: Not sending key/value pair. Only the value so $_POST is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note: You're calling the callback as many times as there are elements on `sort_data` array, which I believe it's not the intended functionality.

Also, you should really check if your `ajax()` call was successful or not. Ajax call has a parameter `method` (instead of `type`) according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Finally, you could write to a file with a one-liner...

So, let's put it all together:

### script.js

```
function finalCoords() {
  var matrix = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < sort_data.length; i++) {
    matrix.push([data.nodes[i].name, sort_data[i].x, sort_data[i].y, sort_data[i].z]); /* This data is collected from other arrays */
  }
  var matrixStr = matrix.join(" "); /* This is the string I want to store */
  console.log(matrixStr); 

  $.ajax({
    url: "matrice.php", /* This is the PHP Medium */
    data: matrixStr,
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    method: 'POST',
    timeout : 5000
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });
}
```

### matrice.php

```
<?php
    $file = "matrice.txt"; /* This is the destination file */
    $text = serialize($_POST);
    file_put_contents($file, $text);
?>
```

That should do the trick and tell if there are any errors with the ajax call.

### EDIT

Taking a cue from the comment from charlietfl (thanks, btw), we should take the raw post data:

```
<?php
    $file = "matrice.txt"; /* This is the destination file */
    $text = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents($file, $text);
?>
```

Comment: $_POST will be empty. Not sending proper data

Comment: Indeed, the file `matrix.txt` is still empty but I believe we're getting close

Comment: Thanks, @charlietfl!